# Electron + Phaser, DRAG/POINTERMOVE event is not catched by Phaser

Tags: electron, phaser-framework

I would like to connect Electron with Phaser 3.0. It seems that everything is working besides mousemove events - I need mouse pointer coordinates as mouse moves. It works in browser but not in electron.

It works with all other events - pointerdown, pointerup etc.

How can I get mouse coordinates from Electron to Phaser?
Thanks for all suggestions!

```
scene.input.on('pointermove', function (pointer, gameObject, dragX, dragY) {
      ...
// this listener is not fired
})

scene.input.on('drag', function (pointer, gameObject, dragX, dragY) {
     ...
// this listener is not fired
})
```

Comment: Can you share your github repo so I can take a look?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal I can't share whole source code. It's possible to reveal small parts - what is needed to resolve this thing?

Comment: May be you talk about this: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15289

Comment: @Oleg thanks for your tip! I am not using webview but I will go through that.. it seems to be a serious issue with electron